# What is Improved Familiar for?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the options for animals you can use as Improved Familiars all seem fairly weak. Pseudodragons aren't really that much better than weasels. My GM says my witch should take this feat, but I'm not sure if it is worth it. Is there any specific reason I should take this?

Comment: Do you know why your GM has suggested your Witch take this feat?

Comment: He said it was a good idea because then I could get a stronger familiar. But there are not many options I can find for interesting new familiars, and none of them are much tougher than, say, a thrush.

Comment: I should clarify, by tough I mean more hit points, not how well a weasel would do against a pseudodragon. A pseudodragon could kill 100 weasels, but how well would it stand up to a freaking kyton? Not better than a weasel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Familiars are not for combat. Not even Improved Familiars. All familiars are fragile creatures. If you want a pet that's of any use in combat, get an Animal Companion (though even those lose relevance at higher levels).

The primary advantage of basic familiars is that they give you a bonus (to *your* save, skill, HP or initiative).

The primary advantage of Improved Familiars is their intelligence (usually), and an extra set of hands. They can scout for you, many have useful spell-like abilities, and since they can use your skill ranks, some of them can be very effective skill users. Particularly cool is a familiar with high Charisma and hands. If you have enough ranks in Use Magic Device, the familiar is able to use wands, which means extra spellcasting actions during combat.

Comment: Unless your familiar *is* an animal companion!  (Looking at you, Mammoth Shaman)

Comment: The UMD ability can be powerful. I had to admit surprise and shock at discovering improved familiars could do this. As a DM I wasnt happy so my players know that while allowed, its something that shouldnt be used very often.

Comment: I really like the Raktavarne Improved familiar... yes, you need do be LE to do that but... Comeon, getting your familiar into a building by selling it to the shopkeeper as a goblet and then having it open the door from within? having it sneak into the bed of an enemy and bite the guy to death when he forgets he was bitten the same moment?! Familiars are for thinking out of the box (and really handy for an unchained rougue)

Answer (score 14):

1. There are a very large number of possibilities for Improved Familiar, see [the list on the d20pfsrd page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar).
2. Even the basic options (imp, quasit) are way better than "a thrush or a weasel." But it's not about combat (a quasit can kill an infinite number of thrushes, but zero of anything that's CR appropriate for you as a level 7+ caster) - it's about options and spell-likes.  Invisible scout? Cast commune every once in a while? At-will detecting various things? Improved familiars have those options and more.

I'm not saying these are always a better choice than using that feat slot for something else - but they're good enough that it's worth looking at.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I did not know you could have a faerie dragon using Improved Familiar.

Comment: As an example from a game I'm playing, my character has a raven familiar. Imps can use *beast form* to turn into ravens, so taking Improved Familiar, I discover that the raven was actually an imp (sent by a greater fiend to assist me... my character has complex backstory). Imps can also use *beast form* to turn into giant spiders, so now in combat I can deploy a giant spider to spin web traps... and it keeps the imp's at-will *invisibility*. Oh, and it can *commune* with a deity or greater fiend to get guidance for me. *Augury* helps there too. And constant *detect magic* is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

My DM allows stacking of improved familiars on generational beings, like elementals.

Aka, take it once, you have a single small elemental. Take it again, and you have a single medium elemental. Etc.

Stacking it like this is really powerful, but the DM makes sure to counter it (who wants a huge fire elemental in a town? The enemies see the elemental from really far away, they focus the giant thing down in a turn and then your out of a familiar for a week, etc.

IIt also makes you really weak, cuz those are much needed feats that the spellcasting classes get few of.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange, Hiace50. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Please take note that we are a Q&A site and not a discussion forum -- we're looking for [evidence-based answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), and answering with homebrew isn't necessarily appropriate for a question asking about the standard benefit of improved familiar. This might meet [our requirements for homebrew answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-homebrew-an-acceptable-answer-to-a-question) though. Also, when you reach 20 rep, you can join us in [chat].