# How does creating sheets of sticky webbing work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, actions

**[Web](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Web-Ex-) (Ex)**

> Web spinners can create sheets of sticky webbing up to three times their size. They usually position these sheets to snare flying creatures but can also try to trap prey on the ground. Approaching creatures must succeed on a DC 20 Perception check to notice a web; otherwise they stumble into it and become trapped as though by a successful web attack. Attempts to escape or burst the webbing gain a +5 bonus if the trapped creature has something to walk on or grab while pulling free. Each 5-foot-square section of web has a number of hit points equal to the Hit Dice of the creature that created it and DR 5/—.

What is "three times their size"? I'm looking at [giant spider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/vermin/spider/giant-spider). So, since a medium-sized creature occupies a 5 ft. square, 5 ft. square × 3? An area of 15 ft.?

Recently, I read [anaximander](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8599/anaximander)'s [comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55633/what-is-improved-familiar-for/55634#comment114487_55634):

> [I]n combat I can deploy a giant spider to spin web traps.

Web is [*probably* a standard action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Use-Special-Ability):

> Those extraordinary abilities that are actions are usually standard actions [...].

So, can a giant spider create a 15 ft. area sheet of sticky webbing as a standard action?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the action to make a web is a standard action because it is not specified otherwise.

> Using a special ability is usually a standard action, but whether it is a standard action, a full-round action, or not an action at all is defined by the ability.

[Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Use-Special-Ability)

For the size of the web, it should be three pieces the exact size of the creature, so three 5 foot squares, not one 15 by 15 square. This matches how similar effects like wall spells work, that are often one 5 or 10 foot square per caster level.